# nginx PHP files 404

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, http-status-code-404

I am getting 404 not found on php files with my nginx/php-fastcgi install.

I have tried several variations of declaring root in different places but cant find one that works, and I suspect this is something to do with it.

Here are my config files, can anyone see what might be wrong/missing?

My nginx.conf;

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /opt/local/var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /opt/local/var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  text/html;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    passenger_root /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.7;
    passenger_ruby /opt/local/bin/ruby;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root   /Users/foo/Sites;

        location / {
            root   /Users/foo/Sites;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi.conf;
        }
    }
}
```

And my fastcgi.conf:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;` from your PHP location and move your root and index directive from `location /` to server level.

Comment: I've tried both and still the same 404. FWIW, I'm getting `*10 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request:` error in the logs.

Comment: Fixed it. It was a permissions problem with php-fastcgi not having sufficient rights.